# Can I open custom hsperfdata_root/PID after process shutdown?

Tags: java, performance, docker, heap-dump

I'm using docker to containerize my application and want to look at it's performance from host machine. I've mapped volume : "/opt/tmp/my_app/:/tmp", which contains hsperfdata_root

- Can I somehow open heap and other information from that hsperfdata_root/PID in jmap or some other tool ?
- Does container must be in Running state for such debugging or it might be shutdown ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JDK includes the `jstat` tool for doing this. Try `jstat -snap file:/tmp/hsperfdata_root`.